# How can I show a object using Ajax in a button with JQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, methods, module, console

In the module `AppInformacionDeRegistro` I have the method `AccionBotonEnviar` , and contains a `click(function()`:

```
AccionBotonEnviar: function(data){

var self = this;      
$("#btn_enviar_formulario_id").click(function(){

    for (var i = 0; i <aContadorEstados.length; i++) {
    var enviar = true;
        if (aContadorEstados[i] == "NO CONTIENE") {
            enviar = false;
        break;
        };
     };
    if (enviar) {
        self.hideError();  
        self.hideSuccess();
        self.validarNombreTrabajador();
    }else{
        self.hideSuccess();
        self.hideErrorTrabajador();
        self.showError();
    };
});  },
```

For now, I need to show the object `objTareas` of the method `datosGuardados` for Chrome's debug console with `console.info()`, using ajax.

```
datosGuardados: function(problema){

var self  = this;

var objTareas = new Object();

objTareas.tareas = aTareas;
objTareas.descripcionProblema = problema;
objTareas.idTareaSeleccionada = $('#nombre_trabajador_id').val();
objTareas.nombreTrabajador = $('#nombre_trabajador_id option:selected').text();

console.info(objTareas);
return objTareas; },
```

Somewhere in the Method `AccionBotonEnviar` , I need to use AJAX to show the method `datosGuardados` by console when i press the button.

How I can do this?

Comment: console.log("Method", yourMethod) doesn't do what you want?

Comment: I need use ajax call in the button to show datosGuardados

Comment: Just check jQuery's out $.get() function then.